# What is the largest golden nonce found?

Tags: nonce

With all the stats and metrics out there I was surprised I could not find this out. Has anyone ever determined the highest nonce in a block?

Comment: Another interesting question would be: "What has been the smallest winning hash so far?"

Comment: @Geremia: That would be 0000000000000000000000bb5b432a764ad6c7acf677dcd99161abfdf68e698e, for block 500174.

Comment: @NateEldredge How did you determine that?

Comment: @Geremia: I wrote a script to scan my local copy of the blockchain.

Comment: @NateEldredge Could you post the script? thanks

Comment: What's a "golden nonce"? The nonce of a mined block?

Comment: @Geremia: It's on my to-do list to put it on github.  I hope to get around to it soon.

Comment: @Geremia: The script is now on github, at https://github.com/neldredge/bitcoin-blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through block 512961, the highest (little-endian) nonce value to date is 4294956079 (`0xffffd42f`), in [block 219742](https://blockchain.info/block/00000000000000a4cffe264a74c86105c1701cd03d26179a2ffa65a071fe9e20).

The lowest is 1082 (`0x0000043a`), in block [67071](https://blockchain.info/block/0000000004085b772b067293e4a09c870254b55b899be1ab05e6cf8a60fc1369).

The script I used to gather this data is at https://github.com/neldredge/bitcoin-blocks.

Comment: I'm jealous of your ability to look that up - thanks!